# What is required to use Vertex Array Objects?

Tags: opengl, glut, glew, vertex-array, vao

I am trying to use Vertex Array Objects in one of my programs, but it seems that my PC don't support this feature.

When I execute this function `glewIsSupported("GL_ARB_vertex_array_object")`, it returns false.

If I try to update my video driver, this could make Vertex Array Objects available?

How can I check wich OpenGL my videocard support?

Vertex Array Objects can be used starting with OpenGL 3.0?

Comment: The easiest way I know of to be able to tell what extensions are supported by some piece of hardware that you may or may not have is the [OpenGL extension viewer database](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/download.php).

Answer (score 3):

VAO - according to spec: http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_array_object.txt are written against OpenGL 2.1.

In OpenGL 3.0 it is in official spec, so when GPU supports OGL 3.0 then VAO are for sure supported.

You can use http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/ to check all OGL extensions.

What GPU do you have?

Via chrome will not support new features from OpenGL 3.0 as you see